# normalize a matrix row-wise in theano

Tags: python, matrix, normalization, theano

Lets say I have a Matrix `N` with size `n_i x n_o` and I want to normalize it row-wise,i.e., 
the sum of each row should be one. How can I do this in theano?

Motivation: using softmax returns back error for me, so I try to kind of sidestep it by implementing my own version of softmax.

Comment: Shouldn't you rather look into fixing the error with the softmax then? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if the following is useful for you:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

m = T.matrix(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
m_normalized = m / m.sum(axis=1).reshape((m.shape[0], 1))

f = theano.function([m], m_normalized)

import numpy as np
a = np.exp(np.random.randn(5, 10)).astype(theano.config.floatX)

b = f(a)
c = a / a.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal
assert_array_equal(b, c)
```

Comment: Instead of the `reshape` after the `sum`, I think `keepdims=True` would be cleaner in `sum`.

Comment: Indeed. I had seen that argument, but have never used it, because I don't think it exists in numpy. But you are right, it is definitely more concise.

Comment: If would be nice if you addressed the divide by zero possibilities; one of the rows can sum to zero.

Comment: Yes, this can be added. The question is how you want to take care of it. You could systematically add a very small number in the denominator, but it has to be orders of magnitude smaller than your smallest nonzero number. Or you actually implement a decision mechanism by using `T.setsubtensor` on a mask or a switch operation.

Comment: Here assert_array_equal raises assertion error because the answers will not be exact due to floating point arithmetic. It could be misleading even though the code is correct.

Comment: Interesting. I am pretty sure it didn't on the machine I tried this on. Otherwise I would have switched to `numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal` to make the comparison a bit more lenient. Feel free to edit the answer!

Answer (score 4):

or you can also use

```
m/m.norm(1, axis=1).reshape((m.shape[0], 1))
```

Comment: That is equivalent iff the sum is positive (which I hope it would be chosen to be). If it is not, then my answer will probably lead to unexpected behavior whereas dividing by the norm will do a simple scaling and not change the sign.